# Object is possibly 'undefined' with BehaviourSubject

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `BehaviourSubject` like:

```
public _position: BehaviorSubject<Position | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
public position$: Observable<Position | undefined> = this._position.asObservable();
public get position() {
  return this._position.getValue();
}
```

which I am trying to use like so:

```
this.position$.subscribe((position) => {
  if (typeof position !== 'undefined') {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  }
});
```

but no matter what I try, I continue to see the Typescript error:

> [ts] Object is possibly 'undefined'.

for `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude`.

I don't understand. I've specified that the type can be either `Position` or `undefined`. I've given it an initial `undefined` value. I've also guarded the variable with `typeof position !== 'undefined'`. What's going on?

Comment: What is type for `position.coords`?

Comment: It should be `Coordinates`

Comment: By the error, it seems that in fact it's `Coordinates | undefined`. I suggest checking the `Position` type definition.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript sometimes gets its knickers in a twist over nothing..

can you try

```
this.position$.subscribe((position) => {
  if (position && position.coords) {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why typescript is showing that error, but the code can be made cleaner:

If you use rxjs > 5 you may have to rewrite the filter and map

```
public _position: BehaviorSubject<Position> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public position$: Observable<Position> = this._position.asObservable();
public get position() {
  return this._position.getValue();
}
```

---

```
this.position$
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(position => position.coords)
    .subscribe((coords) => {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
});
```